# What is my error in my javascript code? I can't find the error

Tags: javascript

This code uses an existing array to fill that data into an empty one...

Then it creates a loop that should check if they are under 18 or greater than and equal to 18.

- Filling the data into the empty array works
- The checking does not work

```js
var years = [1990, 2001, 1975, 2004, 1998, 1993];
var empty = [];
for (i = 0; i <= years.length - 1; i++) {
  empty.push(years[i]);
}
console.log(empty);
for (a = 0; a <= empty.length - 1; a++) {
  if (2018 - empty[a] < 18) {
    console.log(empty[a] + ' is not eighteen or older: ' + 2018 - empty[a]);
  } else {
    console.log(empty[a] + ' is eighteen or older: ' + 2018 - empty[a]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does it throw an error, or it executes without error but gives an unexpected output? What is the output? What output did you expect?

Comment: I expected it to console.log the year and if it is older than 18 and then the age. But it just stops working after the loop places the data from the "years" array to the "empty" array. Any clues?

Comment: But it says "NaN" instead...

Comment: You should add that info to the question body :) You can edit your question, click on the "edit" button to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing has to do with operators, type coercion, and order of evaluation.

Your `console.log` is equivalent to the first one shown below.
You start with a number but then add `+` a string, so the whole thing is coerced to a string.
This continues, with everything as a string including the `+ 2018`, until you hit the minus `-` operator, at
 `+ 2018 - empty[a]`

At that point, minus does not operate on *strings*, and the value up to there is a string, for example:
`"2003 is not eighteen or older: 2018"`
so the attempted subtraction of a number from a string gets you Not-a-Number `NaN`
`"2003 is not eighteen or older: 2018" - empty[a]`

```
console.log ( 5 + ' is five, subtract ' + 2 + ' is ' + 5-2 );
NaN
```

If you parenthesize the numeric expression so it is evaluated *before* concatenation with the string, it should work:

```
console.log ( 5 + ' is five, subtract ' + 2 + ' is ' + (5-2) );
5 is five, subtract 2 is 3
```

e.g. `console.log( empty[a] + ' is not eighteen or older: ' + (2018 - empty[a]) );`

```js
var years = [1990, 2001, 1975, 2004, 1998, 1993];
var empty = [];
for (i = 0; i <= years.length - 1; i++) {
  empty.push(years[i]);
}
console.log(empty);
for (a = 0; a <= empty.length - 1; a++) {
  if (2018 - empty[a] < 18) {
    console.log( empty[a] + ' is not eighteen or older: ' + (2018 - empty[a]) );
  } else {
    console.log( empty[a] + ' is eighteen or older: ' + (2018 - empty[a]) );
  }
}
```

---

Note - this also wouldn't be a problem if you computed the age once, then used it in the console.log output. As it is, you compute `2018 - empty[a]` multiple times.

```
for (a = 0; a <= empty.length - 1; a++) {
    let age = 2018 - empty[a];
    if (age < 18) {
        console.log(empty[a] + ' is not eighteen or older: ' + age);
    ...
```

```js
var years = [1990, 2001, 1975, 2004, 1998, 1993];
var empty = [];
for (i = 0; i <= years.length - 1; i++) {
  empty.push(years[i]);
}
console.log(empty);
for (a = 0; a <= empty.length - 1; a++) {
    let age = 2018 - empty[a];
    if (age < 18) {
        console.log( empty[a] + ' is not eighteen or older: ' + age );
      } else {
        console.log( empty[a] + ' is eighteen or older: ' + age );
      }
    }
```

Comment: var array = [1990,2001,1975];
var emptyArray = [];
for(i=0;i<=array.length-1;i++){
    emptyArray.push(array[i]);
}
for(a=0;a<=emptyArray.length-1;a++){
    if((2018-emptyArray[a])>=18){
        console.log(emptyArray[a]+' is older than 18');
    } else {
        console.log(emptyArray[a]+' is younger than 18');
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with string concatenation. Since `2018` is a number its expecting to do numerical addition in those console logs. I modified your code using template literals instead and it works fine. If you prefer not to use template literals just add brackets around the calculation at the end `2018 - empty[a]` becomes `(2018 - empty[a])`.

```js
var years = [1990, 2001, 1975, 2004, 1998, 1993];
var empty = [];
for (let i = 0; i < years.length; i += 1) {
  empty.push(years[i]);
}
console.log(empty);
// using template literals
for (let a = 0; a < empty.length; a += 1) {
  if (2018 - +empty[a] < 18) {
    console.log(`${empty[a]} is not eighteen or older: ${2018 - empty[a]}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${empty[a]} is eighteen or older: ${2018 - empty[a]}`);
  }
}

// regular string concatenation
for (let a = 0; a < empty.length; a += 1) {
  if (2018 - +empty[a] < 18) {
    console.log(empty[a] + ' is not eighteen or older:' + (2018 - empty[a]));
  } else {
    console.log(empty[a] + ' is eighteen or older:' + (2018 - empty[a]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Was there a way to fix it without using template literals?

Comment: @MarkBinder Edited to include a non template literal response. Just requires brackets around the `2018 - year` section